# TransferUtility S3 resume does not work

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transferutility

I am using TransferUitlty class to upload files to S3. Everything is going fine except that after I pause a upload and resume it. the file is uploading from beginning and not from where I paused.

> Is this resume method designed for restarting the upload or resuming from where it paused?
>
> Can I use resume method to resume upload even after killing app?

CODE:

```
    private void uploadResume(int id,ProgressBar progress,File f,TextView filelength,ImageView updownststatus){
    if(sTransferUtility!=null){

        sTransferUtility.resume(id);
        observer= sTransferUtility.getTransferById(id);
        
        observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener(progress, observer,f,filelength,updownststatus));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design of Amazon S3. You can pause and resume an upload on if it's a multipart upload. See S3 [Multipart Upload Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html). Say you upload a 100Mb file with TransferUtility. The file will be broken into 20 parts, 5mb each, uploaded in parallel. You pause the upload when 3 parts are done and 3 are in process. And you resume it later. TransferUtility will continue the upload from 5mb * 3 = 15mb and it has 17 parts to transfer. That's because each part has be uploaded fully or else it will be discarded.

Comment: If the part is not uploaded completely then it will restart after resuming. If a part is completed then that part won't upload again and remaining parts will start getting uploaded. Indirectly on going part will have to restart if pause and resume happens.Did I understand it properly?

Comment: That's correct. Incomplete part will be restart from beginning.

Comment: Is it possible to track status of each part? Using aws SDK?

Comment: Nope. It's about implementation detail and provides no useful information to developers. What's your use case?

Comment: No particular use with parts. I asked it out of curiosity. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am trying to deviate from the topic, So my answer is basically towards file download.

So I was trying to download a resource from Amazon S3. I used transfer observer to know the state of transfer. I was able to pause the download and monitor it's state. However, I was unable to resume the download even after trying using transferUtility.resume(transferId). But then I tried transferObserver.refresh() and I was able to resume the download for my file.

Comment: HI @Soumen, You can attach a `TransferListener` object with the `TransferObserver` to monitor the state and progress without having to refresh the state continuously.